How do I add localization to a WPF Blazor app?
I am trying to add localization to my WPF Blazor app but it's not working. The IStringLocalizer I inject with shared resource always returns the default English resource even though I set a different culture.
I have made WPF Blazor app before.
I am trying to do this again, but this time I tried adding localization
as per Microsoft's documentation and others
(Except rather than relying on local storage, I rely on a configuration file. I can load the culture info from the configuration and set the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture and DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture with the CultureInfo I want)
This works well for a standard Blazor WASM app but doesn't seem to work for a WPF Blazor app
When I try to get the localized string, it always returns the default English resource.
I suspect it has something to do with the removal of this line
- await builder.Build().RunAsync();
with replacement of
builder.Services.AddLocalization();

var host = builder.Build();

const string defaultCulture = "en-US";

var js = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();
var result = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("blazorCulture.get");
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(result ?? defaultCulture);

if (result == null)
{
    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("blazorCulture.set", defaultCulture);
}

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

await host.RunAsync();

but I don't know how to access the host after it's built, but before it's run. When using WPF Blazor app I can just set up my services for my Blazor components like so
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddWpfBlazorWebView();
        Resources.Add("services", serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider());
    }
}

Does anyone know how to access the host after its built but before its run? Or more preferably how to get localization to work in a WPF Blazor app?
Coincidently, does anyone know why culture must be set after the host is built but before its run? I'm not sure I fully understand how it works.
I also investigated this as it gives access to the host, but I couldn't get the .NET 8 version to work
https://github.com/DotNetExtension/BlazorDesktop
Edits:
Perhaps I should try to use Extensions.Hosting? would that even help?
aha

In this article, you will learn how to use the IStringLocalizer and IStringLocalizerFactory implementations. All of the example source code in this article relies on the Microsoft.Extensions.Localization and Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting NuGet packages. For more information on hosting, see .NET Generic Host.

Maybe it will help

As I mentioned in my edit the reason why it didn't work is in the documentation: I needed Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting hosted application I loosely followed this on how to convert my WPF to a hosted application
Instead of

using Host.CreateDefaultBuilder

I used Host.CreateApplicationBuilder to avoid using the call back structure .NET is moving away from. I just made a Program.cs as my StartupObject in my project file, so it does feel very similar to a .NET 8 blazor app. Everything works now!

In my case, just set the current UICulture and set default thread culture for both (CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture, CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture) under MainWindlow.xaml.cs of your project just like setting up the WPF application with localization.
And do all the other Blazor localization setup. (Add Microsoft.Extensions.Localization and call @localizer in .razor page)
It worked for me.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

hmm did it work with other languages? Mine worked fine with the default culture but didn't load a different resource when I set a different culture.
As explained by my edits, the reason why it didn't work is in the documentation: I needed Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting hosted application.
